# Highcharts start reversed y-axis at 1 for ranking graph

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph showing rankings over a time periods, but I can't figure out how to get the y axis to start at 1 and also label it as 1.

This is the closest I have got

`yAxis: {
            min: 1,
            startOnTick: false,
            reversed: true
        },`

http://jsfiddle.net/270dj43o/

The y-axis starts at 1, but it fails to show it as a tick on the y-axis. (In this example all I need is a 1 above the 2.5 on the y-axis)

This is a graph ranking someones performance over multiple time periods, so it needs to always show 1 instead of 0.

Note I know that setting the tickInterval to 1 makes it display 1, but that isn't viable option in my situation.

Comment: Can you do `yAxis: { min: 0, .. }`?

Comment: @isim, no {min: 0} starts the yAxis at 0. It makes the 0 show up on the yAxis sure, but as this is graphing a ranking, it doesn't make sense to start at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `tickPositioner` function which you can apply on `yAxis` so you can apply your own tick points : http://jsfiddle.net/270dj43o/3/

EDIT: Apart of tickPositioner, you can use also [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions).

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian & Raeen, I ended up using tickPositions, with custom logic to work out the ticks array. (The max ranking on the graph can be anywhere between 5 and 150). Sort of annoying that highcharts doesn't seem to handle the axis starting at a certain number and showing that number as a tick on the axis.